# Load Project Failed

Tags: windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to get a solution to load that I downloaded but the projects give this error when I try to load them:

> [path to .csproj] : error  : Value cannot be null. Parameter name: url

I've scoured the two csproj files for any missing fields but can't find any.

The csproj files are too big to paste here but can be found here: https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-dotnet/tree/master/src/Store at revision 28213de.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled Visual Studio and reinstalled with Windows 8.1 SDK and it started working fine. Just modifying your install does not fix this issue, you ***MUST*** reinstall.